# make an anchor toggle function which appends data to textarea on click and removes on reclick

Tags: javascript, html

i m trying to make an anchor toggle function which appends data to textarea on click and removes on reclick. here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5LdK/).

`

```
function btnsInit()
{
  var i, a = document.getElementById('btns').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) 
 {
     var str=document.getElementById('ta').value; 
     var index= str.indexOf(a[i]);
     if(index!=-1)
    {
    a[i].onclick = btnClick;
    }
     else
    {
    str.replace(a[i],"_");
        }
  }
}
function btnClick(e)
{ 

  document.getElementById('ta').value += this.firstChild.nodeValue + ',';
  xPreventDefault(e);
  return false;
}
```

`Please reply ASAP

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery?

Comment: yea that will do as well.but please use comments and explain :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here...

Comment: What i want is onclick the achor sends the value and it gets appended in textarea.and on reclicking the same link its value gets deleted from the textarea.there will be many links

Comment: guys need a little more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is new js code, you can use it -

```
<div id='btns'>
        <p>
            <!-- adding id to element, helps to maintain the list
            of element which have been clicked, and also helps in
             distinguishing between two elements have same text. 
            Dont forget to add href="#' or href="javascript:void(0)"
             else your page may refresh and form data will be lost -->

            <a id="a1" href='#'>category</a>

        </p>
        <p>
            <a id="a2" href='#'>url</a>

        </p>
    </div>
<textarea id='ta' rows='10' cols='20'></textarea></body>
```

Javascript -

```
window.onload = btnsInit;

var selected = {};//keeps list of selected links

function btnsInit() {
    var i, a = document.getElementById('btns').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        a[i].onclick = btnClick;
    }
}

function btnClick(e) {
    if (selected[this.id]) {
        delete selected[this.id];//deleting if already been clicked
    } else {
        selected[this.id] = this.innerHTML;//adding to the selected list
    }
    updateTextArea();

    xPreventDefault(e);
    return false;
}

function updateTextArea() {
    var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
    var val = "";
    for ( var id in selected) {
        val += selected[id] + ",";
    }
    ta.value = val;//updating from selected list
}

function xPreventDefault(e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else if (window.event)
        window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Problems with your code -

- `btnsInit` was not actually assigning onclick listeners to `<a>` elements.
- Re click on a link was not handled or not handled properly(if handled).
- Use attribute/value `href=' '` for `a` tag which is refreshing the page.

**Update - questions asked in comments**

- *Was my code not working as it was refreshing the page?*

  No, It was not. It was missing reclick handling and `btnsInit` was not working properly.
- *Is delete a predefined function?*

  `delete` is a JavaScript keyword, which delete an object property.
  [About delete keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
- *What is the use of 'this'?*

  `this` is another keyword which holds the reference of the object in context, in this case it holds the element clicked.
  [More about this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but the code is still having issues.If you click on one link and then click on other link the value of first one is getting removed and the value of second link is not getting appended. please check. also can you please add comments and explain your code :) that would really help as i m noew to js.

Comment: ok, Let me check. Its working on my system, but still i would take an another look

Comment: Updated. Please Check it

Comment: Thanks a ton . it worked like a charm. :) Im having some doubts.1) was my code not working as it was refreshing the page? 2) is delete a predefined function? 3 )what is the use of 'this'?

Comment: I update the answer. You can select my answer as right answer if it worked.

Comment: yea i got it please reply to my doubts :)

Comment: hey can you help me a little more

Comment: yea i have made another function that is taking value of cluster(textarea) and breaking it into substrings and saving it in an array .something like monday,tuesday, will be broken into monday tuesday and saved individually as array elements. also these elements will be compared with ids of the anchors just like above and the background of the anchors will be changed if matched.

[link]http://codepad.org/qovTnDp8 here is the code. please help